# add event listeners to global stage via class AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, class

i am making a simple game i want to be able to add an keyboard event lisnter within the class constructor. However i am having trouble. i undertsand you have to pass the stage through a listed display object property stage? anyway i am getting errors that do not recognise my event listener keyboard event.

Best Louis

```
   package louiseguchi.game
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent



    {

        public function keyBoardVelocity extends EventDispatcher ()
        {
            // constructor code

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressUp);

        }
        private static function keyPressUp(Event:KeyboardEvent):void{
            trace("ok")
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class with a public static property that you would assign the stage reference to thereby making the stage accessible throughout the application like in the following:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            GlobalVars.stage = stage;

            var keyboardVelocity:KeyboardVelocity = new KeyboardVelocity();

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package 

import flash.display.Stage;

internal class GlobalVars
{
    public static var stage:Stage;

}// end class

import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

internal class KeyboardVelocity extends EventDispatcher
{
    public function KeyboardVelocity()
    {
        var stage:Stage = GlobalVars.stage;

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onStageKeyDown);

    }// end function

    private function onStageKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void   
    {
        trace("key down");

    }// end function

}// end class
```

Note: I've used internal classes so that you can simply copy and paste the code into you document class and run it. Ideally you would separate the classes into their own files.

Personally I'm not a fan of making objects globally accessible as it poses a potential security risk and is bad practice in my opinion. You should consider simply parsing a reference of the stage to your `KeyboardVelocity` class like in the following:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var keyboardVelocity:KeyboardVelocity = new KeyboardVelocity(stage);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package 

import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

internal class KeyboardVelocity extends EventDispatcher
{
    public function KeyboardVelocity(stage:Stage)
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onStageKeyDown);

    }// end function

    private function onStageKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void   
    {
        trace("key down");

    }// end function

}// end class
```

Comment: @Tuarayi - I agree with you about global static vars, in general. It does rather defeat the purpose of OO patterns. That being said - passing reference to variables in the constructor gets pretty sticky too, and promotes tight coupling. I don't actually think there is a "right" answer on this point, other than "don't use globals unless really needed", and the Stage is one of those that I find myself referencing commonly, and so, is a good candidate. @OP both strategies work, both have potential issues.

Answer (score 1):

A few problems here. For one, your class is malformed. See my comments.

```
  package louiseguchi.game
    {
        import Main; //doc class
        import flash.display.Stage;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
        import flash.ui.Keyboard
        import flash.events.KeyboardEvent

//only classes may be extended
        public class KeyBoardVelocity extends EventDispatcher
        {

    //here is your constructor
            public function KeyBoardVelocity()
            {
                super()
                init()
            }

            private function init():void
            {
                addEventHandlers();
            }


            private function addEventHandlers()
            {
//static access of main stage
                Main.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressUp);
            }

            // instance function
            private function keyPressUp(Event:KeyboardEvent):void{
                trace("ok")
            }

        }

    }
```

Note that I added a few steps in between the constructor and your listener. Do so if you like, but I generally put very little in a constructor.

Secondly, you need to have some object in the display list to access the stage, and generally its accessed via the Main document class. Here, I just have a static get function that references in the document class:

```
package com.b99.testBed //alter as needed
{
    import com.b99.testBed.keypress.KeyBoardVelocity;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author bosworth99
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private static var _stage:Stage;

        public function Main() 
        {
            super();
            init();
        }

        private function init():void
        {
            _stage = this.stage;

            var _candidate:KeyBoardVelocity = new KeyBoardVelocity();

        }

        public static function get stage():Stage { return _stage; }

    }

}
```

You could gain access to the stage in a number of ways, this is the one I generally prefer.

Hope that helps.